# Where does add the path this command: export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, path

I am trying to install `pocketsphinx` and after installation I should run these commands:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

But I am interested to know where does this command add the paths? If I want to do it manually, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing it setting the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the value `/usr/local/lib` & `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the value `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.

The `export` command means that the variables are added to the environment of subsequently executed commands. So whatever you're running after exporting these variables will have access to them.

So your application will be looking for the variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` & `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

Comment: But after restarting, I must do it again. How can I permanent the changes?

Comment: Assuming you are using `bash`, add the two lines to your `~/.bash_profile`.